# animate not working on position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's what I do

When people click button A, div 2 gets a position absolute (I add the class "stuck" to it) and we move to div 2 to cover div 1. I have an arrow in div2 that when you click on it, should animate to the top of the page. Problem is that it is not animating to the top in 750 seconds after I remove the class stuck to div2. I am not sure why.

```
    this.$el.find('.npwfu-bottom').removeClass('stuck');
    $('.mrvl-header-wrapper').removeClass('hide');
    if (this.isOverlay) {
       this.$el.animate({
           scrollTop: 0
        }, 750);
    } else {
       $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 750);
    }
```

Here's the css for stuck:

```
.stuck{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 105;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Problem is that the animation doesn't work. It doesn't transition to the top of page in 750 seconds.

Comment: Post the code you have that shows the issue ... and I guess you meant 750 milliseconds

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `this` is here ?

Comment: yes this works. it animates but doesn't animate it 750 milli seconds

Comment: So how fast is it animating ?

Comment: It animates in 0 seconds

Comment: And are you clicking anything like an anchor with a `...href="#"` etc.